# Magento SQL Deadlock on custom table

Tags: php, sql, magento, deadlock, magento-1.5

I'm looking for some tips on how best to avoid a deadlock in the following scenario.  I have a custom table set up for our Magento site that stores some details about ordered items and how much the profit margin is.  I listen for the **sales_order_invoice_save_after** event and insert rows into the table based on the info in the invoice.  I also compute an estimated profit based on the **actual_shipping_costs** field for every product.  Since this is only an estimate, we regularly import a CSV that contains the order number and the actual cost we paid to ship the order.  My code grabs the imported data, recomputes the profit for the items in each of the orders in the CSV, and updates the database table.  I had initially added a couple of columns to the **sales_flat_order** and **sales_flat_order_items** tables and was storing everything in there rather than having my own custom table.  We started seeing some issues post-checkout for some customers (though we couldn't officially attribute them to my code), in addition to some unforeseen issues with configurable products, so I switched to using a custom table.  This gave me the flexibility I needed and fixed my issues with configurable products.  It also does not seem to cause any issues post-checkout.

This was great until the first time I tried importing a CSV of about 3000 order numbers with shipping costs.  The way I do the import is a bit ghetto but it's the best way I could find to do it.  There are a few settings for my extension under the system config, one of which is a file import field.  If you select that field and choose a CSV file and click "Save" on the configuration page it grabs the file, parses it, and does the work to add/update the necessary rows in my custom table.  Please let me know if you think this is part of the problem and if you have recommendations on what I should do instead (i.e. should I be using the Dataflow classes and creating an advanced profile for this?).  This takes a significant amount of time...much longer than it used to take when I was adding the data to the sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_items tables.  This could be due to extra calculations and locating the parent of any child products...not sure exactly why it's slower, but it is.  While this import is running, if a customer places an order, they can (and likely WILL) get a SQL Deadlock error.

My question (if you're still following all this) is how to best avoid this.  For new orders, they are only inserts into the table, while the import is updating existing rows.  They should never conflict.  The only thing I can think of is that in my code for inserting the new rows I do attempt to load a record to make sure it isn't in the table already...could this be why it's locking?  I'm not a SQL expert by any stretch, but I did find some information online about the different types of locks and setting priorities.  Is this possible through Magento or the Zend framework and would that help?

Sorry for the long-winded question.  I hope you can follow it.  If you need more info, I'll do my best.  Posting the code is hard since it's in so many different files, but let me know what you need and I'll provide what I can.

Thanks!